# How to plot max-in-1h-window of rate-per-1-second of events in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-loki, logql

We have a rate limit of 500 fetches per second from an external API. I want to track how close are we to this limit as the user base grows on a scale of weeks. I don't need the exact rate every second, I need the maximum 1-second-rate in a 1 hour window. The fetches are in bursts so the rate over 1 second can be much higher than the average rate over 1 hour or even 1 minute.

I have a Prometheus counter on the fetches and can use this query:

`max_over_time(sum(rate(fetches_counter_total{namespace="$namespace"}[1m]))[1h:1m])`

This does the max-in-window correctly but only on 1-minute-average-rate and not 1-second-rate. When I change the ending to `[1s]))[1h:1s])` Grafana says "No Data" and no plot is shown.

I thought that maybe Prometheus is not fast enough so I added to the code a log every time a fetch happens and I can get the rate of logs from Loki using this query:

`sum(count_over_time({namespace="$namespace"} |= "Fetch happened log text" [1s]))`

This gives the 1-second-rate accurately but when I set the range to a week there are much less points than seconds in a week and refreshing shows a different subset of points each time. To get the max-in-window I tried this query:

`max_over_time(sum(count_over_time({namespace="$namespace"} |= "Fetch happened log text" [1s]))[5m:1s])`

But it throws an error:
`parse error at line 1, col 15: syntax error: unexpected SUM, expecting NUMBER or { or (`

Now I'm stuck. From the documentation, seems that `unwrap`ing the logs might help but I don't have any labels and don't understand how to apply `unwrap` to this situation.

In summary, is it possible to get 1-second-rate from Prometheus or max_over_time of number of logs from Loki?

Answer (score 1):

In prometheus `rate()` function will always return per-second rate. The amount of time you specify only means "look at that much time to calculate the per-second rate".

So:

```
   rate(metric[5m])
```

means roughly "take last 5 minutes of data for `metric` and calculate average per-second rate of events counted by `metric` *in that time range*".

Prometheus has to have at least two data points in the time range specified there to calculate rate, so if `metric` has a data point roughly every `1m` then even `[1m]` might be too short (cause data points are close to the limits of time window that it looks in). Probably minimum time range used should be > 3*$scrape interval (if you want to handle random missing samples - if not then > 3*$scrape_interval )

From this I gather that your original query might be correct (assuming you have >1 data point in your metric per minute).

If you have a scrape interval for this data that is <1 second then this is rather unusual for Prometheus and I don't think it will work well. Review how often do you have your data points and adjust the time range used accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The events come in burst, we can have no fetches for 2 minutes, then 120 in a single second. If I use `rate()` in this event, I will get 1 event per second on average while the result I need is that the maximum is 120 events per second in this time frame.
Do you suggest lowering the scrape interval to <1 second? Is there another solution?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to solve the task in Prometheus, but it can be easily solved in VictoriaMetrics with [rollup_rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup_rate) and [label_match](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_match) functions:

```
label_match(
  rollup_rate(fetches_counter_total[1h]),
  "rollup",
  "max",
)
```

See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for more details.